# Rails how to straight 3 row conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following syntax error, and I don't understand why:

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

I'm trying to direct the user to option 3 if option 1 or 2 are not used, so I did:

```
<%if order.dispute.status == "open" %>

  <li>
    <%= button_to 'Dispute Open',  order_dispute_path(order), method: :get, class: 'btn_grey' %>
  </li>

<% elsif %>

  <li>
    <%= button_to 'Dispute',  new_order_dispute_path(order), method: :get, class: 'btn_grey' %>
  </li>

<% else %>

  <li>
    <%= button_to 'Dispute closed',  closed_order_dispute_path, method: :get, class: 'btn_grey' %>
  </li>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent, which may seem like a trivial thing, but following a consistent pattern will help you understand your own logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just write `<% elsif %>` by itself.

> Else if **what**??

What you've written makes as much sense as:

```
if
  puts "this"
else
  puts "that"
end
```

(Which is also illegal syntax, of course.)

I'm guessing you meant to write something like:

```
<% elsif order.dispute.nil? %>
```

Comment: thank you but so i have to stay with 2 if else statement? 
and about a third option?
and elsif is ilegal why exist?

Comment: "else IF" requires a *condition*. Just like a plain "IF" requires a condition. Like I said above: "else if **what?**" It's illegal syntax to write "elsif" without a condition, because that makes no sense.

Comment: Or to put that another way, how do you want to decide between showing option 2 vs option 3? Pretend option 1 doesn't exist, for a moment -- how would you write that?

Comment: if option 2.present?
blah
else
bloh